# Making a Detailview Field Invisible and Acessible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a  DataBound DetailsViewControl . for displaying  some  questions and answer option and the correct answer

```
  <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                    CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Vertical" 
                    Height="50px" Width="477px" ForeColor="Black">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
                            SortExpression="Question" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 1" HeaderText="Answer 1" 
                            SortExpression="Answer 1" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 2" HeaderText="Answer 2" 
                            SortExpression="Answer 2" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 3" HeaderText="Answer 3" 
                            SortExpression="Answer 3" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 4" HeaderText="Answer 4" 
                            SortExpression="Answer 4" />
                        <asp:BoundField   DataField="Correct Answer" HeaderText="Correct"
                          SortExpression="Correct Answer" >
                        <FooterStyle BorderColor="White" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" SortExpression="Id" />
                    </Fields>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:DetailsView>
```

But I want to hide the  correct answer field from the user  I tried to make the CorrectAnswer feild invisible from Designer and I succeed but my issue is when I try to read  the value of Invisible feild

```
a.CorrectAnswer = DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text;
```

I am getting Empty String as the value from the invisible Details View field

Can anyone suggest any way of making a the field invisible but keeping the value accessible to code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `CssClass` to `invisible`

```
CssClass="invisible"
```

and create the ivisible css class:

```
.invisible {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Css class of that feild only isnt it?

Comment: Yes, you can set the css class to invisible of any ASP control which should become invisible.